# CypherDSL, ReactiveCypherdslStatementExecutor.findOne() not working properly

Tags: neo4j, cypher, cypher-dsl

I'm using CypherDSL to retrieve a specific node from Neo4j; but the returned entity is missing its @Relationship attributes. The entity is something like:

```java
    @Node
    @Builder
    @Data
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @EqualsAndHashCode(exclude = {"children", "visibleEntities"})
    @ToString(exclude = {"children", "visibleEntities"})
    public class VisibilityGroup {
    
        public static final String CAN_SEE_REL_TYPE ="CAN_SEE";
        public static final String CONTAINS_REL_TYPE ="CONTAINS";
    
        public static final String ENTITY_ID_PROPERTY= "entityId";
    
    
        @DynamicLabels
        @Singular(ignoreNullCollections = true)
        private List<String> labels;
    
        @Property("name")
        private String nodeName;
    
        @Property(ENTITY_ID_PROPERTY)
        private UUID entityId;
    
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(generatorClass = UUIDStringGenerator.class)
        private String id;
    
        @Relationship(type = CONTAINS_REL_TYPE, direction = Relationship.Direction.OUTGOING)
        @Builder.Default
        private Set<VisibilityGroupRelationship> children = new HashSet<>();
    
        @Relationship(type = CAN_SEE_REL_TYPE, direction = Relationship.Direction.OUTGOING)
        @Builder.Default
        private Set<VisibilityGroupRelationship> visibleEntities = new HashSet<>();
    
        ........
    }
```

> Now: **if I use ReactiveCrudRepository.findById(ID id) the object has
> children and visibleEntities correctly initialized**, but if I get it
> using CypherDSL they are both null.

Here my repo code:

```java
    default Mono<VisibilityGroup> findEntity(UUID originEntityId, String originType,
                                             UUID targetEntityId, String targetType,
                                             boolean useContains){
 
  
            Node targetNode = Cypher.node(targetType)
                .named("target")
                .withProperties(VisibilityGroup.ENTITY_ID_PROPERTY,
                    Cypher.literalOf(targetEntityId.toString()));
            Node originNode = Cypher.node(originType)
                .named("origin")
                .withProperties(VisibilityGroup.ENTITY_ID_PROPERTY,
                    Cypher.literalOf(originEntityId.toString()));
            Relationship relationship = useContains ?
                originNode.relationshipTo(targetNode, VisibilityGroup.CAN_SEE_REL_TYPE,
                    VisibilityGroup.CONTAINS_REL_TYPE).unbounded() :
                originNode.relationshipTo(targetNode, VisibilityGroup.CAN_SEE_REL_TYPE).unbounded();
            SymbolicName permissionVariable = Cypher.name("p");
            ResultStatement statement = Cypher.match(relationship)
                .where(....)
                .returningDistinct(targetNode).build();
            return findOne(statement);
        }
```

I know, I can easily fix it replacing the last line with:

```java
      return findOne(statement).flatMap(visibilityGroup -> findById(visibilityGroup.getId()));
```

but I would like to know if this is normal, or if I'm misusing CypherDSL.
Thank you  in advance.

UPDATE

I add a textual description of the model and of the intended result. All nodes are bound together with "CAN_SEE" or "CONTAINS" relations, defining a visibility graph. Only admins can "see" through CONTAINS relations; all users can see through "CAN_SEE" relations. The proposed repository method discovers if the origin node (a user, normally) CAN_SEE* (or CAN_SEE|CONTAINS*) the target node, and this works just well. The returned node is the requested target node, if visible. What I need is that the returned target node contains ITS neighbors as attributes:

1. what nodes are DIRECTLY (1 hop) bound to target node with a CAN_SEE relationship, in the visibleEntities attribute;
2. what nodes are DIRECTLY (1 hop) bound to him with a CONTAINS relationship, in the children attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Please use the following in your return clause:

```java
ResultStatement statement = Cypher.match(relationship)
    //  .where(....)
    .returningDistinct(originNode.getRequiredSymbolicName(), Functions.collect(relationship).as("r"), Functions.collect(targetNode).as("t"))
        .build();
```

Basically what you have to do is when using custom queries is to shape the returned subgraph into one record per entity (which is what SDN normally does with the generated queries), this is described here: [Getting one record per root node](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/current/reference/html/#custom-queries.for-relationships.one.record) and as a Cypher-DSL [example](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/current/reference/html/#sdn-mixins.using-cypher-dsl-statements) and under [Using complex, dynamic custom queries but still returning domain types](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/current/reference/html/#faq.custom-queries-and-custom-mappings)

I am the author of Cypher-DSL and co-maintainer of SDN, so thank you for using both :)

*Update after comment*

Note that I queried the relationships in the same direction like in your model now, speaking from the PoV from the target node (they are outgoing from its view)

```java
Node targetNode = Cypher.node(targetType)
    .named("target")
    .withProperties(VisibilityGroup.ENTITY_ID_PROPERTY,
            Cypher.literalOf(targetEntityId.toString()));
Node originNode = Cypher.node(originType)
    .named("origin")
    .withProperties(VisibilityGroup.ENTITY_ID_PROPERTY,
            Cypher.literalOf(originEntityId.toString()));
Relationship relationship = useContains ?
    targetNode.relationshipTo(originNode, VisibilityGroup.CAN_SEE_REL_TYPE, VisibilityGroup.CONTAINS_REL_TYPE).unbounded() :
    targetNode.relationshipTo(originNode, VisibilityGroup.CAN_SEE_REL_TYPE).unbounded();

SymbolicName permissionVariable = Cypher.name("p");

// Needed individually for collection

Condition condition = Conditions.noCondition();
// Build your where clause…
condition = condition.and(permissionVariable.isTrue());

ResultStatement statement;
if(useContains) {
    NamedPath p = Cypher.path("path").definedBy(relationship);
    statement = Cypher.match(targetNode, p)
            .where(condition)
            .returning(targetNode.getRequiredSymbolicName(), Functions.relationships(p).as("r"), Functions.nodes(p).as("o"))
            .build();
} else {
    Relationship canSee = targetNode.relationshipTo(originNode, VisibilityGroup.CAN_SEE_REL_TYPE).named("canSee");
    Relationship contains = targetNode.relationshipTo(originNode, VisibilityGroup.CONTAINS_REL_TYPE).named("contains");
    statement = Cypher.match(relationship)
            .where(condition)
            .with(originNode, targetNode)
            .match(canSee, contains)
            .returningDistinct(targetNode.getRequiredSymbolicName(), Functions.collect(canSee).add(Functions.collect(contains)).as("r"), Functions.collect(originNode).as("o"))
            .build();
}
```

The condition of course leads to invalid cypher with this, as `p` is undefined, but I guess the idea is clear.

This would generate something like this when using the `CONTAINS` relationship

```
MATCH (target:target {entityId: 'dcfb30c2-8a09-41d2-ba35-d1199f25ed69'}), path = (target)-[:CAN_SEE|CONTAINS*]->(origin:origin {entityId: 'e8a41c34-a2b0-479b-8b34-40bc1b6d0656'})
WHERE p = true
RETURN target, relationships(path) AS r, nodes(path) AS o
```

in which you can use the fact that you already are matching all of the types

or when not using it, something like this

```
MATCH (target:target {entityId: '7cb5cd5e-c8b1-48f7-8e5f-aad70ab19d15'})-[:CAN_SEE*]->(origin:origin {entityId: '66530792-5704-4732-98be-aea6b64b5fb6'})
WHERE p = true
WITH origin, target
MATCH (target)-[canSee:CAN_SEE]->(origin), (target)-[contains:CONTAINS]->(origin)
RETURN DISTINCT target, (collect(canSee) + collect(contains)) AS r, collect(origin) AS o
```

Please test the optimisation, I am not sure if always all relationships are contained when using the `|` or operator from the top of my head.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I'm still in trouble. I don't need to get the originNode, but the targetNode with its children... I tried replacing originNode with targetNode in your answer, without result (children and visibleEntities are still null). I think that the wrong part is Functions.collect(targetNode).as("t")... but I don't understand what to write there...

Comment: Please note that the target entity class has two different attributes for different children: children linked to targetNode with a "CAN_SEE" relation should be stored in the visibleEntities attribute, whereas children linked with a "CONTAINS" relation should go to the children attribute. How can I collect both of them?

Comment: Thank you for your effort, but I think that you misunderstand my model, I try to explain better... if you have still time please read the updated description (last part)

Comment: I'm not searching from targetNode to originNode, but from origin to target; then I need the neighbors of the targetNode, e.g what other nodes are linked (outgoing) to the target node.